# Motion tracking: I have a solve. Now how to get the camera position for each video frame?

Tags: camera, tracking, motion-capture

TLDR: I've solved camera motion for a video clip. How can I export each camera's position and rotation to "real", unconstrained camera objects?

---

I'm using Blender's motiong tracking tools to reconstruct 3D spaces from still images (from an old game I love). I added in two image "frames", set up a bunch of tracking points, solved it (with 0.20px error, good enough for my purposes) and clicked "Setup tracking scene" to export the whole thing to my 3D workspace. Now I can press the arrow keys to jump between frames so I can see my 3D space from each solved camera position.

[image]

[image]

But I want to export each frame's camera position to a "real" camera object so that it stays in my scene even if I delete the empties etc. How can I do this? When I look at the properties for the 3D camera object, the position and rotation values don't change as I switch between camera positions, even though the camera clearly did move several meters.

I tried selecting the camera then clicking Object -> Constraints -> Clear object constraints, but this resets to the first frame in the video clip, so I don't see how to get camera coords for subsequent frames.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76256/bake-follow-track-constraint-to-f-curve and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180912/i-have-a-camera-solver-on-a-camera-how-can-i-delete-the-solver-on-a-duplicate-c/180914#180914 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170949/connect-points-of-motion-tracks-with-smoothed-lines/175837#175837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you solve a camera using tracking, blender creates a Camera Solver Constraint.

To clear such constraint, convert the camera motion to keyframes.

Select the camera and use **Constraint to F-Curve** in the Object Constraint Properties.

[image]

More info:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/motion_tracking/camera_solver.html

Comment: can I export also track feature points?